# Jackson can't read field declared in super class

Tags: java, jackson

I have this parent class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "objectType")
@JsonSubTypes(
    {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child"),
    }
)
public class Parent {
    @JsonProperty("objectType")
    private ProductType productType

    public ProductType getProductType { return productType; }
}
```

This class is extended by a child class:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @JsonProperty("field1")
    private Field1 field1;
    @JsonProperty("field2")
    private Field2 field2;
}
```

I try to parse the following Json file representing a serialized instance of `Child` class:

```
{
    "objectType" : "child1",
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : "value2"
}
```

... with the following code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
Parent parent = objectMapper.treeToValue(parentJsonNode, Parent.class);
```

(p.s. `parentJsonNode` is a `JsonNode` created by reading a JSON file).

What happens is that the `field1` and `field2` of my object are correctly read and set, however the field `objectType` (declared into the parent class) remains `null` after parsing.

What should I do to make Jackson read the value `child` of `objectType` correctly from the Json object?

Here is the code for the `ProductType`:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum ProductType {

    CHILD1("child1"), CHILD2("child2");

    private String objectType;

    private ProductType(String objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getObjectType() {  return objectType; }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code for `ProductType`. Also, are the getters and setters missing or just omitted?

Comment: @Smutje sorry, done. The getters are omitted, but I have no setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the strange behaviour of Jackson to add an additional field non-explicitly visible to you during compile time to distinguish between the subclasses named like the value you put in `@JsonTypeInfo`. Because your parent class contains a property serialized into a JSON property named `objectType` and the name of the denominator given in `@JsonTypeInfo` also being `objectType`. If you would *serialize* an object of `Child` you would notice that the serialized object contains two fields with identical name `objectType` where only one of them would be filled:

```
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Child()));
```

leads to

```
{"objectType":"child","objectType":null,"field1":null,"field2":null}
```

The workaround is to either skip the explicit field `productType` (serialized as `objectType`) in the parent class if you don't need it in your code, or give it a different name for serialization (e.g. `productType`), but then you need to of course have a second JSON field to be deserialized into it:

Changing

```
public class Parent {

    @JsonProperty("objectType")
    private String productType;
```

to

```
public class Parent {

    @JsonProperty("productType")
    private String productType;
```

and

```
Parent parent = objectMapper.treeToValue(objectMapper.readTree("{\n" +
    "    \"objectType\" : \"child\",\n" +
    "    \"productType\" : \"child\",\n" +
    "    \"field1\" : \"value1\",\n" +
    "    \"field2\" : \"value2\"\n" +
    "}"), Parent.class);
System.out.println(parent.getProductType());
```

leads to the output

```
child
```

A third possibility would be to initialize the field explicitly, e.g. via constructor, because Jackson uses the default constructor to create the objects on deserialization:

```
// For subclasses
protected Parent (String productType) {
    this.productType = productType;
}

// For Jackson
public Parent () {
}
```

and

```
public Child () {
    super("child");
}
```

Edit: I used `String` instead of `ProductType` to ease up my code but the result is similar.